# What is the job of a controller?

Tags: controller, fpga, i2c, can-bus

I have the following Image:
https://ibb.co/cSCBWQ

So, There is a FPGA and in it is a I2C and a CAN Controller.
What is the Job/Task of the I2C and CAN Controller?

For What do I need those?

What are they doing?

Answer (score 0):

They are serial communications interfaces.

CAN is often used for automotive communications.
I2C is often used for peripheral device communications e.g. PROM or ADC.

They will allow you to communicate between the FPGA and other devices.

This is a fairly broad question and is similar to asking what does the english language do and why do I need a language.

Answer (score 0):

I2C and CAN are two communication bus standards.

For such buses to function properly, communication must be made in an orderly manner, in compliance with the respective communication protocols designed for the bus. These protocols regulate formalities such as: how to interpret the information passed on the bus, how and when to send information on the bus, how to coexist with other bus users, etc.

The controllers are the gateways for these buses. On their system-side, they usually provide a primitive interface (e.g. a parallel, I/O and register based interface), whereas on their bus side they will implement and comply with the bus' communication protocols.